# How to change default IDE of openIdea gradle task

Tags: android-studio, gradle, intellij-idea

I have 2 IDEs: Android Studio and Intellij Ultimate. Whenever running:

```
gradle openIdea
```

to invoke open IDE task for idea project, this command always prompt Android Studio, how can i change default IDE to Intellij for this command.

Comment: Please check your  OS associations for .iml files.

Answer (score 0):

The idea plugin must be looking for the first instance of idea it can find.

A simple workaround is to rename 'AndroidStudio' as 'zAndroidStudio'.

Answer (score 0):

If you use macOS, `gradle openIdea` just runs `open ~.ipr`.

Please check file associations, as y.bedrov says.

Reference: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/0b8f53c9eba8abf75515b1d6b9ff44b24ded5332/subprojects/ide/src/main/java/org/gradle/plugins/ide/internal/IdePlugin.java#L183-L209